# Google Maps Android API v2 not show the map

Tags: android, google-maps

I've a problem to show a map using the Google Map Android API v2.

The app debug dont show any error but when I call the Activity I get a blank MapView with no map inside.

My code is:

activity_map.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
>

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

MapViewerActivity

```
public class MapViewerActivity extends Activity {

    MapView mapView;
    GoogleMap map;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
    map = mapView.getMap();
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    MapsInitializer.initialize(this);

    // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(43.1, -87.9), 10);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
}
```

Any idea? Tyvm for read!

Comment: is the google logo showing?

Comment: could you please post the manifest too..

Comment: post your manifest, are you getting certificate from console? is the rigth sha1 certificate?

Answer (score 1):

From Google's documenation:

> To use the Google Maps Android API v2, you must register your app project on the Google Developers Console and get a Google API key which you can add to your app. The type of API key you need is an Android key.

Follow Google's instructions here to set up a maps API key

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/signup

In short:

- Make a project in the Google Developers Console
- Generate a key to use the Maps API
- Add the key to your android manifest

Comment: It's registed, and the API Key added, other ideas? :(

Comment: Like someone else asked, is there a google logo showing on the map?

Comment: This means that the API key you added to the google console is incorrect. You need to follow the directions in the link in my answer to get the correct key.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

activity_map

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MapViewerActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

MapViewerActivity

```
public class MapViewerActivity extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Sydney")
                .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
                .position(sydney));
    }
}
```

Finally make sure you have added the following features & permissions in manifest,

```
        <uses-feature
                android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
                android:required="true"/>

  <!-- Creating Permission to receive Google Maps -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <!-- Permission to receive Google Maps -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

     <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

**Make sure you are using a correct API key and your Google Maps v2 is enabled in API console.**